# How do I redistribute applications that use SAP Crystal Reports for Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, crystal-reports

I have just encountered a scenario where my application, that makes use of SAP Crystal Reports for Visual Studio 2012. The app won't run without Crystal installed, and Crystal won't install without Visual Studio. There must be a re distributable for just the reports and viewer that I'm missing. Where can I find this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The redistributable files are listed on the [SAP website](http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-7824)

Comment: Yes, but that site is an orgy of confusion. I thought I might get a straight (lazy) answer here, i.e. straight directions.

Comment: @Panzercrisis What additional information is there to include? (that is a permalink, by the way)

Answer (score 0):

You can find the latest redistributable installers here https://www.crystalreports.com/crvs/confirm/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to include them as prerequisite in your prefered installer you need static urls.

Up to CR 13.0.26 you can use the link below (alter the version in the link)
http://downloads.businessobjects.com/akdlm/crnetruntime/clickonce/CRRuntime_32bit_13_0_26.msi

Unfortunatelly starting from CR 13.0.27 the old download links do no longer work. 
Use the base link [https://origin.softwaredownloads.sap.com/public/file/[SomeID]](https://origin.softwaredownloads.sap.com/public/file/%5BSomeID%5D)

Some of the IDs are listed here:
https://www.tektutorialshub.com/crystal-reports/how-to-download-and-install-crystal-report-runtime/

Latest ones here:
https://www.crystalreports.com/crvs/confirm/
Note that they include a redirect encoded in the url. So basically they point to origin.softwaredownloads.sap.com

e.g. CR 13.0.27 x86
https://origin.softwaredownloads.sap.com/public/file/0020000000543412020